# How to get the text of link that generated by javaScript with Selenium/Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

The hyperlink is

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="showStaLine(this); return false;">Apple</a>
```

I tried this code to get the text of link 'Apple'. However, it return None.

```
self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//tr[@id="'+ item +'"]/td[4]').get_attribute('href')
```

Anybody may help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: what happens when you click that link

Comment: your locator doesn't point to a tag at all

Comment: use `text` property instead of `get_attribute` method

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Thanks (Snippet of html is to small, do not show outer html, that is pointed in your xpath)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution based on that rare information could be:

1. Change your xpath to point on the `<a>`:

   ```
   //tr[@id="'+ item +'"]/td[4]/a
   ```
2. Use `.text` instead of `get_attribute('href')` to get the text of the `<a>`

**Example**

```
self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//tr[@id="'+ item +'"]/td[4]/a').text
```

**Output**

> Apple